# Understanding the set of neighbors of a set

Tags: graph-theory

For a graph G(V, E), the Hall's theorem states

> If for every subset X of V we have that |N(X)| ≥ |X|, then G has a
>   perfect matching

where N(X) represents the set of neighbors of the set X in G.

So reading the definition of the [graph neighbourhood](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphNeighborhood.html) on wikipedia, it states:

> The graph neighborhood of a vertex v in a graph is the set of all the
>   vertices adjacent to v including v itself.

So for me |N(X)| is at least |X| since I need to take in account the vertices of the subset X and hence I have troubles to understand how it's possible to have |N(X)| < |X| for a given subset in the graph.

Did I look into the wrong definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) two kinds of neighborhoods commonly appearing in statements about graphs. The *closed* neighborhood of a vertex $v$ is the set of all vertices adjacent to $v$ together with $v$ itself. The *open* neighborhood of $v$ is the set of all vertices adjacent to $v$ excluding $v$ itself. These are sometimes denoted by $\overline{N(v)}$ and $N(v)$, respectively, to avoid confusion (though I wouldn't rely on this convention without stating it explicitly in my writing).

The requirement $|N(X)| \geq |X|$ in Hall's Marriage Theorem refers to open neighborhoods of bipartite graphs. The idea is that it is certainly necessary that every subset of the left partite should have enough neighbors in the right partite set: if three vertices on the left can only see two vertices on the right, there is no way to match them. The real content of Hall's Theorem is that this condition is also sufficient.